# Tabela em Python

Tags: python-3.x, lista, tupla

Boa noite,

Preciso fazer uma função Python que receba uma lista de tuplas com as cotações do dólar em reais e de reais em dólares retorne um string que, quando impresso, gere uma tabela de cotações.

Não consegui gerar a tabela. Alguém pode me auxiliar? Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Seu programa não está funcionando pelo jeito que você está tendo acessar os elementos dentro da sua tupla. No código `print(f'US${lista[posição(0)]: <15}', end= '=')` ,  `posicao` é um inteiro, que você está usando para acessar o dentro de `lista` o objeto no índice "posição" que no seu caso é uma tupla. Então o correto seria  `lista[posição][0]`. Primeiro você obtem a tupla e então acessa o index dela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá para simplificar bastante o código. Por exemplo, ao dividir `1 / cotação_dólar`, o resultado já será um `float` (pois a cotação já é um `float`), então não precisa forçar o resultado para `float`. E para construir a lista do exercício 7, pode usar um `range` e eliminar algumas variáveis:

```
def exercício_7(cotação_dólar):
    lista = []
    for valor in range(1, 101):
        lista.append((valor, valor * cotação_dólar)) # dólar, real
        lista.append((valor, valor / cotação_dólar)) # real, dólar
    return lista
```

Usei o `range(1, 101)` porque o valor final não é incluso (ou seja, este `range` pega os números de 1 a 100).

Já o exercício 8 recebe a lista retornada pelo exercício 7 (e não a cotação). E para imprimir do jeito que precisa, basta testar se o índice é par ou ímpar e tratar os valores de acordo:

```
def exercício_8(cotacoes): # recebe a lista de cotações
    for posição in range(len(cotacoes)):
        valor1, valor2 = cotacoes[posição] # valor1 e valor2 são os valores da tupla
        if posição % 2 == 0:
            currency1, currency2, end = 'US$', 'R$ ', '   '
        else:
            currency1, currency2, end = 'R$ ', 'US$', '\n'
        print(f'{currency1}{valor1:>8.2f} = {currency2}{valor2:>8.2f}', end=end)

        if end == '\n':
            print('-' * 25, ' ', '-' * 25)
```

Ou seja, para cada elemento da lista de cotações, eu pego os 2 valores e vejo se eles correspondem a dólar ou real (baseado nos índices pares ou ímpares). Eu também vejo se é para pular a linha ou imprimir na mesma, e só coloco os traços se tiver pulado a linha.

Para formatar os números com 2 casas decimais usei `>8.2f` (alinha à direita ocupando 8 posições, e com 2 casas decimais). Ajuste o tamanho para o que precisar, e [leia a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) para ver todas as opções disponíveis.

Para usar as funções, basta pegar a lista retornada pelo exercício 7 e passar para o 8:

```
cotação_dólar = float(input("Insira a cotação do dólar: "))
cotacoes = exercício_7(cotação_dólar)
exercício_8(cotacoes)
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
exercício_8(exercício_7(float(input("Insira a cotação do dólar: "))))
```

A saída será algo assim (usei a cotação igual a 5 nesse exemplo):

```
US$    1.00 = R$     5.00   R$     1.00 = US$    0.20
-------------------------   -------------------------
US$    2.00 = R$    10.00   R$     2.00 = US$    0.40
-------------------------   -------------------------
US$    3.00 = R$    15.00   R$     3.00 = US$    0.60
-------------------------   -------------------------
etc...
```

---

Outra opção para iterar de 2 em 2 é usando [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), que cria um iterador a partir da lista, e [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), que percorre vários iteráveis ao mesmo tempo. Assim, eu posso percorrer o mesmo iterador, e o resultado será um *loop* que percorre a lista de 2 em 2:

```
def exercício_8(cotacoes):
    iterador = iter(cotacoes)
    currency1, currency2 = 'US$', 'R$ '
    for (v1, v2), (v3, v4) in zip(iterador, iterador):
        print (f'{currency1}{v1:>8.2f} = {currency2}{v2:>8.2f}   {currency2}{v3:>8.2f} = {currency1}{v4:>8.2f}')
        print('-' * 25, ' ', '-' * 25)
```

---

E se quiser deixar o tamanho configurável:

```
def exercício_8(cotacoes):
    tamanho = 8 # mude o tamanho que cada número vai ocupar
    # calcula o restante com base no tamanho
    formato = f'>{tamanho}.2f'
    hífens = '-' * (tamanho * 2 + 9)
    footer = f'{hífens}   {hífens}'

    iterador = iter(cotacoes)
    currency1, currency2 = 'US$', 'R$ '
    for (v1, v2), (v3, v4) in zip(iterador, iterador):
        print (f'{currency1}{v1:{formato}} = {currency2}{v2:{formato}}   {currency2}{v3:{formato}} = {currency1}{v4:{formato}}')
        print(footer)
```